# Add multiple relationships at one time using Cipher Query Language ERROR MSG "WITH is required between CREATE and MATCH"

Tags: neo4j

I'm new to Neo4J and having an issue with adding data to the DB.   I'm using Neo4J community edition running locally, so I'm entering all queries through the web interface.

I'm building a concept map using tweets as a learning exercise.   I've added three types of nodes already like these:

TWEET NODES

```
CREATE (t0:Tweet {id: '0', twitterId: 'ke', twitterName: 'KennyDMcC', created_at: '04/11/2022', text: '@calebsaysthings And as far as we know she’s still goin.   #uk #england #scotland #wales #greatbritain #lanarkshire #glasgow #politics #monarchy #TheQueen', src_url: 'http://twitter.com/download/iphone'})
CREATE (t125:Tweet {id: '125', twitterId: 'ke', twitterName: 'kennethmac2000', created_at: '04/11/2022', text: '@Baldred @Lindy_Loo15 @DalgetySusan @scotgov Hear, hear.  Also Linda, are you seriously suggesting that it should be a criminal offence for a Canadian national to come to the UK and participate in UK politics? If not, Im not sure what you are suggesting.', src_url: 'https://mobile.twitter.com'})
CREATE (t1:Tweet {id: '1', twitterId: 'ca', twitterName: 'cath_data', created_at: '04/11/2022', text: '@RagingAnecdotes Must be nice to have options: ', src_url: 'https://mobile.twitter.com'})
```

TWITTERERS

```
CREATE (ke:Twitterer {id: 'ke', name: 'KennyDMcC'})
CREATE (ca:Twitterer {id: 'ca', name: 'cath_data'})
CREATE (re:Twitterer {id: 're', name: 'Record_Politics'})
```

HASHTAGS

```
CREATE (uk:HashTag {id: 'uk', tag: '#uk'})
CREATE (england:HashTag {id: 'england', tag: '#england'})
CREATE (scotland:HashTag {id: 'scotland', tag: '#scotland'})
```

All of this works as expected and I've been able to add approximately 500 tweets, 125 twitterers and 100 or so Hashtags.   I've done this by creating a python script that creates the CREATE statements and writes them to a text file.  I then copy/paste the queries into neo4j  browser.

The problem I'm having is when I try to do the same thing with setting relationships.  I can add the following individually, but as soon as I try to add them like I was able to add the nodes, copy/paste the whole list, I get an error message.

```
MATCH (t:Tweet),(h:HashTag)
WHERE t.id = '72' AND h.id = 'fordereport'
CREATE (t)-[w40:TAGGED {date: '04/11/2022'}]->(h)

MATCH (t:Tweet),(h:HashTag)
WHERE t.id = '72' AND h.id = 'hypocrisy'
CREATE (t)-[w41:TAGGED {date: '04/11/2022'}]->(h)

MATCH (t:Tweet),(h:HashTag)
WHERE t.id = '75' AND h.id = 'nhs'
CREATE (t)-[w42:TAGGED {date: '04/11/2022'}]->(h)
```

The error message says

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError
WITH is required between CREATE and MATCH (line 5, column 1 (offset: 126))
"MATCH (t:Tweet),(h:HashTag)"
 ^
```

I've tried a number of different ways to enter the data, but haven't been able to get the right format.  I have multiple relationships to build and I really don't want to have to build 1000 relationships one by one.

I have the "Enable multi statement query editor" checked settings.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Answer!   I guess it is too much of a noob question to be easy to find.

a  `;` between the queries solves this issue.   This is what I produced that worked.

```
MATCH (t:Tweet),(h:HashTag)
WHERE t.id = '0' AND h.id = 'uk'
CREATE (t)-[w1:TAGGED {date: '04/11/2022'}]->(h)
;
MATCH (t:Tweet),(h:HashTag)
WHERE t.id = '0' AND h.id = 'england'
CREATE (t)-[w2:TAGGED {date: '04/11/2022'}]->(h)
;
MATCH (t:Tweet),(h:HashTag)
WHERE t.id = '0' AND h.id = 'scotland'
CREATE (t)-[w3:TAGGED {date: '04/11/2022'}]->(h)
;
```